# How to change default font size when preview open microsoft excel document?

Tags: macos, ms-office, preview

I use macbook air, Preview is brilliant, But seems can not zoom out microsoft document(word, excel), So I want to change the default font size.

But how?

Answer (score 1):

Enter the following command into the terminal. Quit and relaunch Preview.

```
defaults write com.apple.Preview NSSystemFontSize -int X
```

Change X to desired font size.

Source: http://www.macosxtips.co.uk/index_files/13-things-you-didnt-know-about-preview.php

*Oh, and to Apple - ever heard of UI?!*